# Fixing Canvas speed bug

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new to programming with JavaScript and working with the canvas.

I'm writing a game as a side project for fun. I've come across a bug in my game where the background will start to speed up faster and faster when the user mouse clicks the screen on various and unpredictable places. My game moves Player1 and the background in increments based on Player1 speed. My best guess is somehow when the user clicks the screen this.drawX += this.speed is calculated multiple times before the loop restarts and requestAnimationFrame is called. Here is a code snippet for the map and player draw function. This function is a prototype of the player object.

```
 // Canvas Context's
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var ctxBg = canvasBg.getContext('2d');
var canvasPlanets = document.getElementById('canvasPlanets');
var ctxPlanets = canvasPlanets.getContext('2d');
var canvasShip = document.getElementById('canvasShip');
var ctxShip = canvasShip.getContext('2d');
var canvasHUD = document.getElementById('canvasHUD');
var ctxHUD = canvasHUD.getContext('2d');
var canvasWindow = document.getElementById('canvasWindow');
var ctxWindow = canvasWindow.getContext('2d');
var canvasButtons = document.getElementById('canvasButtons');
var ctxButtons = canvasButtons.getContext('2d');
// ----------------------------------End Canvas Context
ctxHUD.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctxHUD.font = "bold 20px Arial";

ctxWindow.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctxWindow.font = "bold 16px Helvica";

var MAXspeed = 10;
var MINspeed = 2;
var inSpace = true;
var onSurface = false;
// Objects 
var Player1;
var Planet1;
var Resource_0001;
var LandBtn = new Button(560,380,"Land");
var SpaceBtn = new Button(710,10,"Orbit");
var CloseBtn = new Button(620,140,"Close");
    CloseBtn.srcY = 60;
    CloseBtn.srcW = 39;
    CloseBtn.srcH = 39;
    CloseBtn.width = 39;
    CloseBtn.height = 39;
    CloseBtn.showText = false;

//-----end Objects
var SurfaceX = 0;
var SurfaceMap = 0;
var SurfaceMap2 = -1600;

var SpaceMapX = 0;
var SpaceMapY = 0;


var Flag = false;

var gameWidth = canvasBg.width;
var gameHeight = canvasBg.height;
var mouseX = -1;
var mouseY = -1;
var mouseIsDown = false;
var isPlaying = false;
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame;


// Load Images

var imgMap = new Image();
imgMap.src = 'images/Bg.png';

var imgButtons = new Image();
imgButtons.src = 'images/button_sprite.png';

var windowIsOpen = false;
var imgBlueWindow = new Image();
imgBlueWindow.src = 'images/blue_window.png';

var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = 'images/sprite.png';
var imgPlanets = new Image();
imgPlanets.src = 'images/earthlike_p1.png';
var imgBluesky1 = new Image();
imgBluesky1.src = 'images/bluesky1.png';


// ------------- End Loading Images


ctxBg.drawImage(imgMap,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
imgMap.addEventListener('load',init,false);





// Main Functions

function init(){
    Player1 = new Ship();
    Planet1 = new Planet();
    Planet2 = new Planet();
    Planet2.coordX = 2434;
    Planet2.coordY = 2550;
    Planet2.height = 75;
    Planet2.width = 75;
    Planet2.planetType = "Medium Earthlike."
    document.addEventListener('keydown',checkKeyDown,false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup',checkKeyUp,false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkMouseDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", checkMouseUp, false);
    startLoop();
}



function loop() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        clearCtx();
        Player1.draw();
        Planet1.draw();
        Planet2.draw();
        if(Player1.speed >= MAXspeed) Player1.speed = MAXspeed;
        if(Player1.speed <= MINspeed) Player1.speed = MINspeed;
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }
}

function startLoop() {
    clearCtx();
    clearMouse();
    isPlaying = true;
    if(inSpace) loop();
    if(onSurface) planetSurface();
}

function stopLoop() {
    isPlaying = false;
}
// End of main functions

function ifClicked(obj){
    if(mouseX >= obj.drawX && mouseX <= obj.drawX + obj.width){
        if(mouseY >= obj.drawY && mouseY <= obj.drawY + obj.height){
            obj.isClicked = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        obj.isClicked = false;
    }

    if(obj.onSurface === true){
        if(mouseX >= obj.surfX && mouseX <= obj.surfX + obj.width){
            if(mouseY >= obj.surfY && mouseY <= obj.surfY + obj.height){
                obj.isClicked = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            obj.isClicked = false;
        }

    }
}

function landOnSurface(){
    inSpace = false;
    onSurface = true;
    Resource_0001 = new Resource("Wood");
    Resource_0002 = new Resource("Alloy");
    Resource_0002.coordX = 1600;
    Player1.speed = 10;
    Player1.onSurface = true;
    startLoop();
}

function planetSurface(){
    if (isPlaying) {
        if(onSurface){
            clearCtx();
            Player1.draw();
            Resource_0001.draw();
            Resource_0002.draw();
            SpaceBtn.draw();
            if(Player1.speed >= MAXspeed) Player1.speed = MAXspeed;
            if(Player1.speed <= MINspeed) Player1.speed = MINspeed;
            requestAnimFrame(planetSurface);
        }
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------OBJECTS

// ---------------Button Object --------------------------------------->>>>>>

function Button(X,Y,TYPE){
    this.drawX = X || 0; // 560
    this.drawY = Y || 0; // 380
    this.buttonType = TYPE || "";
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.srcH = 30;
    this.srcW = 70;
    this.width = 70;
    this.height = 30;
    this.isClicked = false;
    this.showText = true;

}
Button.prototype.draw = function(){
        ctxButtons.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctxButtons.font = "bold 14px Helvica";
        ctxButtons.shadowColor = "#000";
        ctxButtons.shadowBlur = 2;
        ctxButtons.shadowOffsetX = 2;
        ctxButtons.shadowOffsetY = 2;
        ctxButtons.drawImage(imgButtons,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
        if(this.showText) ctxButtons.fillText(" " + this.buttonType,this.drawX + 15,this.drawY + 20);

};
Button.prototype.wasClicked = function(){
    ifClicked(this);
    if(this.isClicked){
        if(this.buttonType === "Land"){
            stopLoop();
            windowIsOpen = false;
            landOnSurface();
        }
        if(this.buttonType === ""){
            ctxButtons.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
        }
        if(this.buttonType === "Orbit"){
            stopLoop();
            inSpace = true;
            onSurface = false;
            Player1.speed = MINspeed;
            Player1.onSurface = false;
            startLoop();
        }
        if(this.buttonType === "Close"){
            windowIsOpen = false;
            ctxButtons.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
            ctxWindow.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
            startLoop();
        }
    }
};

//----------------------------------------------- End of Button Object -----------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

//--------------------------------- Resource Nodes ---------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>

function Resource(TYPE){

    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 70;
    this.srcH = 75;
    this.srcW = 75;
    this.width = 25;
    this.height = 25;
    this.coordX = -1020;
    this.drawY = 420;
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SurfaceX;
    this.ResourceType = TYPE || "Water";
    this.isClicked = false;
}
Resource.prototype.getResourceType = function(){
    if(this.ResourceType === "Oil") this.srcX = 0;
    if(this.ResourceType === "Alloy") this.srcX = 75;
    if(this.ResourceType === "Wood") this.srcX = 150;
    if(this.ResourceType === "Diamond") this.srcX = 225;
    if(this.ResourceType === "Organics") this.srcX = 300;
    if(this.ResourceType === "Water") this.srcX = 375;
};
Resource.prototype.draw = function(){
        ctxPlanets.shadowColor = "#222";
        ctxPlanets.shadowBlur = 1;
        ctxPlanets.shadowOffsetX = 2;
        ctxPlanets.shadowOffsetY = 2;
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SurfaceX;
    this.getResourceType();
    ifClicked(this);
    if(this.isClicked) this.openWindow();
    ctxPlanets.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
};
Resource.prototype.openWindow = function(){
    ctxWindow.drawImage(imgBlueWindow,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxWindow.fillText("Resource Type: " + this.ResourceType, 220,210);
    windowIsOpen = true;
    CloseBtn.draw();
    stopLoop();
};
//-----------------------------------End Of Resource Nodes ------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
// Planet Functions

function Planet(){

    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.srcW = 100;
    this.srcH = 100;
    this.width = 50;
    this.height = 50;
    this.coordX = 400;
    this.coordY = 400;
    this.planetType = "Small Earthlike."
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SpaceMapX;
    this.drawY = this.coordY - SpaceMapY;
    this.isClicked = false;
    this.nearShip = false;
}
Planet.prototype.draw = function(){
    this.drawX = this.coordX - SpaceMapX;
    this.drawY = this.coordY - SpaceMapY;
    ctxPlanets.drawImage(imgPlanets,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
    ifClicked(this);
    if(this.isClicked) this.openWindow();
    this.shipInRange(Player1);

};
Planet.prototype.shipInRange = function(obj){
    if(obj.drawX + obj.width >= this.drawX - (obj.width * 2) || obj.drawY + obj.height >= this.drawY - (obj.height * 2)){
        this.nearShip = true;
    }
    if(obj.drawX + obj.width <= this.drawX - (obj.width * 2) || obj.drawY + obj.height <= this.drawY - (obj.height * 2)){
         this.nearShip = false;
    }
    if(obj.drawX >= this.drawX + this.width + (obj.width * 2) || obj.drawY >= this.drawY + this.height + (obj.height * 2)){
         this.nearShip = false;
    }
};

Planet.prototype.openWindow = function(){
    ctxButtons.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxWindow.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    if(this.nearShip){
        LandBtn.draw();
    }
    CloseBtn.draw();
    ctxWindow.drawImage(imgBlueWindow,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxWindow.fillText("Planet Type: " + this.planetType, 220,210);
    windowIsOpen = true;
    stopLoop();

};

function DrawSurfaceImg(){
    if(SurfaceMap2 >= 0) SurfaceMap2 = -1600;
    if(SurfaceMap2 < -1600) SurfaceMap2 = -1;
    if(SurfaceMap >= 1600) SurfaceMap = 0;
    if(SurfaceMap < 0) SurfaceMap = 1599;


    ctxBg.drawImage(imgBluesky1, 0, 0, 1600, gameHeight, SurfaceMap, 0, 1600, gameHeight);
    ctxBg.drawImage(imgBluesky1, 0, 0, 1600, gameHeight, SurfaceMap2, 0, 1600, gameHeight);
}
//------------------------End of Planet Functions

// Bullet Functions

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Bullet(){
    this.speed = 5;
    this.drawX = -100;
    this.drawY = 0;
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 60;
    this.width = 20;
    this.height = 20;

}
Bullet.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.drawX += this.speed;
    ctxShip.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);
    if (this.drawX > gameWidth) this.recycle();
};
Bullet.prototype.fire = function(X,Y) {
    this.drawX = X;
    this.drawY = Y;
};

Bullet.prototype.recycle = function() {
    this.drawX = -100;
};

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// end of Bullet Functions

// Ship functions

function Ship(){
    this.classOfShip = "One man pod.";
    this.srcX = 0;
    this.srcY = 0;
    this.srcW = 60;
    this.srcH = 60;
    this.drawX = 0;
    this.drawY = 0;
    this.surfX = 210;
    this.surfY = 0;
    this.noseX = this.drawX;
    this.noseY = this.drawY;
    this.width = 35;
    this.height = 35;
    this.speed = MINspeed;
    this.edgeY = Math.round(gameHeight - this.height - this.speed);
    this.edgeX = Math.round(gameWidth - this.width - this.speed);
    this.isUpKey = false;
    this.isDownKey = false;
    this.isLeftKey = false;
    this.isRightKey = false;
    this.isSpacebar = false;
    this.isShooting = false;
    this.isMoving = false;
    this.isClicked = false;
    this.onSurface = false;

/*------------------------------
    this.bullets = [];
    this.currentBullet = 0;
    this.maxBullets = 25;    
    for (var i = 0; i < this.maxBullets; i++) this.bullets[this.bullets.length] = new Bullet(this);
----------------------------------*/
}
Ship.prototype.draw = function() {
    this.updateCoords();
    this.checkPos();
    this.updateHUD();
    ifClicked(this);
    if(this.isClicked) this.openWindow();
    if(inSpace) ctxShip.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.height,this.width);
    if(onSurface) ctxShip.drawImage(imgSprite,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.srcW,this.srcH,this.surfX,this.surfY,this.height,this.width); 


    //this.checkShooting();
    //this.drawAllBullets();    
};
Ship.prototype.updateHUD = function(){
  if(inSpace){
    ctxHUD.fillStyle = "#fff";
  //    ctxHUD.fillText("mouseX: " + mouseX + " mouseY: " + mouseY,490,30);
    ctxHUD.fillText("Speed: " +  Math.round(this.speed), 60,30);
  }
  if(onSurface){
    ctxHUD.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctxHUD.fillText("SurfaceX: " + SurfaceX, 20,60);
    ctxHUD.fillText("Speed: " +  Math.round(this.speed), 20,30);
   // ctxHUD.fillText("mouseX: " + mouseX + " mouseY: " + mouseY,300,30);
  }
};
Ship.prototype.checkPos = function (){
    var flybuffer = 0;
    var max_X = 0; 
    var max_Y = 0; 
    var speed = Math.round(this.speed);
    if(onSurface){
        max_X = 2000000;
        max_Y = gameHeight;
        flybuffer = 220;
        speed = 10;
        if(!mouseIsDown){
            if (this.isUpKey) {
                if(this.surfY > 0) this.surfY -= speed;
            }
            if (this.isRightKey && SurfaceMap < max_X) {
                SurfaceMap -= speed;
                SurfaceMap2 -= speed;
                SurfaceX += speed;
                if(this.surfX < this.edgeX - 200) this.surfX += speed;
            }
            if (this.isDownKey) {
                if(this.surfY <= gameHeight - flybuffer) this.surfY += speed;
            }
            if (this.isLeftKey) {
                SurfaceMap += speed;
                SurfaceMap2 += speed;
                SurfaceX -= speed;
                if(this.surfX > 200) this.surfX -= speed;
            }
        }
        DrawSurfaceImg();
    }
    if(inSpace ){

        max_X = 2180; // No Higher! Map bugs out, this is the threshold.
        max_Y = 2490; // No Higher! Map bugs out, this is the threshold.
        flybuffer = 90;
        if(!mouseIsDown){
            if (this.isUpKey && SpaceMapY > 0) {
                if(this.drawY > flybuffer) this.drawY -= speed;
                if(SpaceMapY < flybuffer) this.drawY -=  speed;
                SpaceMapY -= speed;
            }
            if (this.isRightKey && SpaceMapX < max_X) {
                if(this.drawX < this.edgeX - flybuffer) this.drawX += speed;
                if(SpaceMapX > max_X - flybuffer) this.drawX += speed;
                SpaceMapX += speed;
            }  
            if (this.isDownKey && SpaceMapY < max_Y) {
                if(this.drawY < this.edgeY - flybuffer) this.drawY += speed;
                if(SpaceMapY > max_Y - flybuffer) this.drawY += speed;
                SpaceMapY += speed;
            }
            if (this.isLeftKey && SpaceMapX > 0) {
                if(this.drawX > flybuffer) this.drawX -= speed;
                if(SpaceMapX < flybuffer) this.drawX -= speed;
                SpaceMapX -= speed;
            }
        }
        ctxBg.drawImage(imgMap,SpaceMapX,SpaceMapY,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    }
};
Ship.prototype.updateCoords = function(){
    if(this.isUpKey) this.srcX = 360;
    if(this.isDownKey) this.srcX = 120;
    if(this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 240;
    if(this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 0;
    if(this.isUpKey && this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 300;
    if(this.isUpKey && this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 420;
    if(this.isDownKey && this.isLeftKey) this.srcX = 180;
    if(this.isDownKey && this.isRightKey) this.srcX = 60;
    this.noseX = (this.drawX + this.width) - this.speed;
    this.noseY = (this.drawY + this.height) - this.speed;
    this.leftX = this.drawX;
    this.rightX = this.drawX + this.width;
    this.topY = this.drawY;
    this.bottomY = this.drawY + this.height;

};
Ship.prototype.openWindow = function(){
    ctxWindow.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctxWindow.font = "bold 15px Helvica";
    ctxWindow.drawImage(imgBlueWindow,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight,0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxWindow.fillText("Class: " + this.classOfShip, 220,210);
    ctxWindow.fillText("Speed: " + this.speed, 220,225);
    windowIsOpen = true;
    if(onSurface){
        ctxWindow.fillText("Resources Found at " + Resource_0001.coordX + " and " + Resource_0002.coordX, 220,240);
    }
    CloseBtn.draw();
        stopLoop();
};
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ship.prototype.checkShooting = function() {
    if (this.isSpacebar && !this.isShooting) {
        this.isShooting = true;
        this.bullets[this.currentBullet].fire(this.noseX, this.noseY);
        this.currentBullet++;
        if (this.currentBullet >= this.bullets.length) this.currentBullet = 0;
    } else if (!this.isSpacebar) {
        this.isShooting = false;
    }
};
Ship.prototype.drawAllBullets = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
        if (this.bullets[i].drawX >= 0) this.bullets[i].draw();
    }
};
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


function clearCtx() {
    ctxShip.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxBg.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxHUD.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxPlanets.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxWindow.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
    ctxButtons.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
}


// end of Ship function
//----------------------------------------------------END OF OBJECTS

// Event Functions

function clearMouse(){
    if(inSpace){
        mouseX = 10000;
        mouseY = 10000;
    }
    if(onSurface){
        var tempX = Math.abs(SurfaceX);
        mouseY = gameHeight + 100;
    }

}

function checkMouseDown(e) {
    var mX = (e.clientX - (canvasBg.offsetLeft - canvasBg.scrollLeft));
    var mY = (e.clientY - (canvasBg.offsetTop - canvasBg.scrollTop));
    if(mX <= gameWidth && mX >= 0) mouseX = mX;
    if(mY <= gameHeight && mY >= 0) mouseY = mY;
    mouseIsDown = true;
    LandBtn.wasClicked();
    SpaceBtn.wasClicked();
    CloseBtn.wasClicked();
}

function checkMouseUp(e){
    mouseIsDown = false;
    clearMouse();
}
function checkKeyDown(e){
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyID === 38 || keyID === 87){ // up arrow or W key
        Player1.isUpKey = true;
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 39|| keyID === 68){ // right arrow or D key
        Player1.isRightKey = true;
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(keyID === 40 || keyID === 83){ // down arrow or S key
        Player1.isDownKey = true;
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 37 || keyID === 65){ // left arrow or A key
        Player1.isLeftKey = true;
        Player1.isMoving = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    /*
    if (keyID === 32) { //spacebar
        Player1.isSpacebar = true;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    */
}
function checkKeyUp(e){
    var keyID = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyID === 38 || keyID === 87){ // up arrow or W key
        Player1.isUpKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 39|| keyID === 68){ // right arrow or D key
        Player1.isRightKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(keyID === 40 || keyID === 83){ // down arrow or S key
        Player1.isDownKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }   
    if(keyID === 37 || keyID === 65){ // left arrow or A key
        Player1.isLeftKey = false;
        Player1.isMoving = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    /*
    if (keyID === 32) { //spacebar
        Player1.isSpacebar = false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    */

}

// end of Event Functions
```

Comment: The problem is probably related to the code where you start your loop. Could you paste in that part as well?

Comment: I added the whole code. Ive changed it alot over the past few days trying to fix this bug. There are also two different places so far the player can go. I find the bug happens on the planet surface. If you want to text drive the code visit www.rinwebsolutions.com/Game/

Comment: Following your advice and looking outside of the checkPos function i think what is happening is the ship is being re-landed on the planet because it thinks the "Land" button from the window is still there even though the context was cleared.

Comment: I dont think thats it either. It seems to happen clicking near the ship.

Comment: Thought i would add another detail. It seems i cant replicate the bug when speed is less than 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my bug. I thought i would answer in case someone runs into a similar problem.

My bug had to do with my button objects. On each click my checkMouseDown function calls a wasClicked function to check if a button object has been clicked. My button object get created before the loop starts and my wasClicked function did not have any logic to detect whether the button had been drawn yet.  So i added another variable to the button object this.isDrawn; i then added this.isDrawn = true; to the draw() function and wrote and if(this.isDrawn) statement to the wasClicked function and the this.isDrawn = false to the logic if the object had been clicked after drawn.

Thanks Ken for guiding me away from my ship drawing functions =)